# Does Windows Phone support EAP SIM?

Tags: wifi, sim

My carrier here in *Brazil* provide some **WiFi** hotspots for theirs customers as a way to avoid them to worry about the data plan.

You don't need a password you just need you phone has compatibility (perhaps through an app) to do the authentication via **EAP SIM**.

Does Windows Phone support it? If so, in witch version?

More info about this service for other phone O.S. in my carrier [here](http://www.claro.com.br/internet/conheca-a-claro-internet/claro-wi-fi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EAP info is kind of scarce. Some Nokia devices claim to support this starting with WP 8 like the 920 - [spec](http://www.nokia.com/fr-fr/mobiles/telephone-portable/lumia920/fiche-technique/) but in general it is said that all devices updated to WP 8.1 will now support it. You can get the free developer preview for your phone now from [here](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/preview-for-developers/178ac8a1-6519-4a0b-960c-038393741e96)

[image]

EAP method:SIM

Comment: I can confirm that my Lumia 920 didn't work with EAP-SIM when it had Windows Phone 8.0.

Comment: But now with Windows Phone 8.1 it just works.